# How to create a function to delete multiple files/images from directories?

Tags: php, function

This is how I am currently trying to setup the function:

```
/** Deletes any images and associated thumbnails */
function deleteImages() {
$_POST['deleteImage'] = array();
$selectedImages = $_POST['deleteImage'];
foreach($selectedImages as $selectedImage) {
unlink(GALLERY_IMG_PATH."/".GALLERY_IMG_FULLSIZE."/".$selectedImage);
unlink(GALLERY_IMG_PATH."/".GALLERY_IMG_THUMB."/".$selectedImage);
}
}
```

I'm using the following to display the form and image(s) with the gallery:

```
<form action="Admin?admin_action=<?php echo $results['formAction']?>" 
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadFile">
<?php
    $directory = "GALLERY_IMG_PATH."/".GALLERY_IMG_FULLSIZE."/";
    $images = glob("$directory*.{jpg,png,webp}", GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $filepath = $image;
        $filename = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $basename = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
?>
<label class="centered_label" for="deleteImage" title="Click here to delete 
current image.">Delete Image:<input type="checkbox" name="deleteImage" 
id="deleteImage" value="<?php echo $basename?>"></label>
<img id="postImage" src="<?php echo $image;?>" title="<?php echo 
preg_replace('/\_/', ' ',$filename)?>." alt="<?php echo 
preg_replace('/\_/', ' ',$filename)?>.">
<?php } ?>
<label class="centered_label" for="images[]" title="This field is to upload 
an image/images for the Image Gallery.">Select image/images to 
upload</label>
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" accept="image/*" 
multiple="multiple" placeholder="Upload an image/images.">
<input type="submit" name="uploadImages" value="UploadImages/SaveChanges" 
title="Click/tap here to save/upload image(s)/save changes. You will be 
returned to Admin Homepage.">
<input class="cancel" type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" 
title="Click/tap here to cancel and exit Image Gallery Uploader. You will 
be returned to Admin Homepage." formnovalidate onclick="history.go(-1)">
</form>
```

I've edited my original post here to reflect how I'm attempting to delete images for the gallery edit form. I can't seem to get it to work. I can however get it to work when I select one individually in which case both the fullsize and thumbnail is deleted. That is what I want for each deletion. The problem I'm having is when I attempt to do multiple images selected. Above is the attempted **deleteImages function()** I can not get to work.

Comment: unlink multiple files or all files ?

Comment: @Dilek - I'm using checkboxes. Each checkbox is to delete both the fullsize and the the associated thumbnail only.

Comment: Check this tutorial for deleting multiple images in same directory : https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/unlink-files-with-paths/40674/9?u=kocdilek1977 and this post for deleting multiple files from multiple directories : https://www.daniweb.com/posts/jump/2146971

Comment: your (php) code has quite some syntax errors, you should clean it up before doing anything else.

Comment: @Dilek - As the setup is displayed on this post images will be displayed to the form with a checkbox for each image if images are in the directory for the fullsize image. But it isn't even displaying the images right now because the script is triggering errors in which case my php error handler is taking effect.